# Fix line wrapping in external commands

Tags: external-command

Sometimes when I have a vim instance open for a long time, I'll notice that newlines no longer reset the column in external commands:

```
:! echo a; echo b
[No write since last change]
a
 b

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Manually inserting carriage returns still works, but that's not always an option.

If I background vim with `CTRL-Z`, I see the same behaviour from my shell, which I can fix with a `reset`.

```
zsh: suspended vim .
                    %
$ echo a; echo b
a
 b
$ reset
$ echo a; echo b
a
b
```

But the issue returns if I foreground vim

```
$ fg
[1]  + continued  vim .
...
:! echo a; echo b
[No write since last change]
a
 b

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I tried `:redraw!`, but no change.

I can always close my vim instance and open a new one, but I'd like to know if there's a fix I can make within vim.

Comment: Hm... do you have some mappings with escape on the left-hand side? Can you reproduce this with `vim --clean` or `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: I’ve yet to discover the steps to recreate; but I’ll keep trying